# google script access spreadsheet by ss name

Tags: google-apps-script

I am scraping a few pages every day and need to create a new google sheet in order to put the scraped data in it.

I am looping through the pages and if it is the first page, I create a new ss with the date as a name.

Then for subsequent pages, I am trying to get this same page by name reference in order to add the data from page 2,3,...

Here is the code:

```
if(start==1){
    // Create new ss in current folder
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(full_d);
    var id = ss.getId();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ABC');
    folder.addFile(file);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file); 
  }else{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(full_d);
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

If I delete the if statement and just put var ss = Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(), my code works.

Thanks

Comment: What is full_d?

Comment: it is today's date. That is the name I want the file to have.

Comment: What sheet do you want this data to be put into?`ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);`

Comment: In the file named full_d. First sheet of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

1. The sheet in the created Spreadsheet using `getSheets()` was given.
2. When start is not 1, an error occurs at `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(full_d);`. So it was modified that the spreadsheet with the filename of `full_d` is opened.
3. The scope of `ss` was considered. But in GAS, this may not be a problem.

### Modified script :

```
var ss; // <--- Added
if(start==1){
  // Create new ss in current folder
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(full_d);
  var id = ss.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ABC');
  folder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file); 
  ss = ss.getSheets()[0]; // <--- Added
}else{
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(full_d).next(); // <--- Added
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0]; // <--- Added
}
ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. At that time, please tell me.